# onbeforeunload not run correct in IOS browser

Tags: ios, onbeforeunload

I've used "onbeforeunload" for my page to confirm when user "unload" page. But it not run correct on IOS browser (safari, chrome, firefox on Iphone). I didn't found any solution for this problem.
This is my sample code

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){return "Are you sure leave this page!";}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know if the page has been left you can use `document.unload`. It works fine in ios browsers. If you see on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) you'll find that it's deprecated and they recommend to use `document.pagehide`

> **Supported Events**
>  
>  Be aware of all the events that iOS supports and under what conditions
>  they are generated. Table 6-1 specifies which events are generated by
>  Safari on iOS and which are generated conditionally depending on the
>  type of element selected. This table also lists unsupported events.
>  
>   **iOS Note:** Although drag and drop are not supported, you can
>  produce the same effect using touch events as described in Adding !
>  Interactive Control to Visual Effects. The load and unload events may
>   not work as expected for back and forward optimization. Use the !
>  pageshow and pagehide events instead

Comment: Thank for your reply! But when I try to use pagehide, I can't create dialog for user confirm stay or leave this page! I really want create a dialog for user confirm stay or leave page, not only run some script when `pagehide`. I think IOS brower not support for this?

Comment: Have you try document.unload ?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it. But I can't prevent unload action when user want to stay on page :(